# Insert Trigger Subtracting Values

Tags: sql, triggers

I'm currently working on a mini project that involves a couple of tables: `Invoice` and `Inventory`

Both of these tables have a `Product_Id` and a `Quantity` and I need to write a trigger so that when a new `Invoice` is created (inserted) it will decrement the product's quantity in the `Inventory` table. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_UpdateQuantity
ON Invoice
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  UPDATE Inventory 
    SET Inventory.Quantity = Inventory.Quantity - Invoice.Quantity
    FROM Invoice
    WHERE Inventory.Product_Id = Invoice.Product_Id
END
```

Comment: Which dbms? (Most dbms products are not ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to triggers.)

Comment: If you also have a table that records goods received, it would be far better to do away with the quantity column in the inventory table entirely. You would always be able to *derive* the quantity on hand based on the transactional data (you could implement some indexed views so that this information was readily available if needed). Always prefer not to store *calculated* data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using SQL Server based on the syntax that you've attempted.

You can do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_UpdateQuantity
ON Invoice
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE 
@ProductId numeric,
@Quantity numeric

    SELECT @ProductId = INSERTED.Product_Id,
          @Quantity = INSERTED.quantity
    FROM INSERTED

  UPDATE Inventory 
    SET Quantity = Quantity - @Quantity
    WHERE Product_Id = @ProductId

END;
```

Basically you capture the Product_Id and Quantity from the INSERTED table and use them in your UPDATE statement.  See the MSDN documentation on the INSERTED table here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

As mentioned by @Damien_The_Unbeliever in a comment under your question, if you have any control over your schema you should consider NOT storing derived data.  You can easily get at the data through a view or other structure without the possibility of the data getting out of sync.

Update to original/accepted answer: as others have pointed out, the above does not account for inserting more than one record, in which case you need to join to the INSERTED table.

Comment: This "looks correct" I will try this first thing when I get home tonight. As for @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is currently a roughed out school assignment to get 2 different types of triggers to work on our made up DB so not currently in a live enviorment thanks for the advice btw its greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: This trigger is broken. It assumes that `inserted` contains a single row, which is not a safe assumption.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better if you do this for bulk insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_UpdateQuantity ON Invoice
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

   UPDATE inv
   SET Quantity = Quantity - i.Quantity
   FROM Inventory inv
   JOIN (SELECT Product_ID, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM INSERTED GROUP BY Product_ID) i ON inv.Product_ID = i.Product_ID

END;
```