# Nullify an inserting value in a row trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a problem with my database trigger in which I'm supposed to nullify the inserted/updated value (`RESULTATOBT`), although I need the OLD/NEW variables, so I can't apply [this solution (updating the table in the table trigger)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799454/insert-trigger-subtracting-values).

The error is a mutating table one; due to modifying a table in a *for each row* trigger.

Here's the concerned extract of my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VERIF_RESULTATS
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF RESULTATOBT
  ON PARTICIPATION
  FOR EACH ROW
  FOLLOWS VERIF_PARTICIPATION
  WHEN ( NEW.RESULTATOBT IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN 
  UPDATE PARTICIPATION p
  SET RESULTATOBT = NULL
  WHERE p.CDPERS = :NEW.CDPERS
    AND p.CDCOMPET = :NEW.CDCOMPET;
END;
/
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

N.B.: I'm a relatively new member, so I might require additional advices/edits if my question doesn't fit the proper format.

Comment: You didn't say what's wrong with it.

Comment: I guess you're getting a mutating table error maybe? It really helps to include the error you get in the question, possibly along with the insert/update statement that generated the error. What is `VERIF_PARTICIPATION` doing, as it is before or after insert/update? You might just be able to null the value - by assignment, not another update statement - within that, if it's before insert/update. Triggers might not be the best approach for whatever you are doing though - hiding business logic in a trigger is painful and confusing.

Comment: @Littlefoot Whoops, sorry.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes I do. Thank you for the advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `before` trigger and simply assign NULL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VERIF_RESULTATS
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF RESULTATOBT
  ON PARTICIPATION
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN ( NEW.RESULTATOBT IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN 
  :new.RESULTATOBT := NULL;
END;
/
```

Comment: Ah, the := operator... :-/ Thank you. 

By the way, I see that you used the _new_ keyword without the ":", is it unnecessary?

Comment: @PrometheosII: I simply forgot the `:` (switching between Postgres and Oracle too often)